# Conditional/dymanic colour foramatting in excel

Tags: excel

Please help for conditional/dymanic colour foramatting in excel

For a cell, eg in row 2, cell `B2`, a drop down list can let user to select a value/text.

Then, based on the content of `cell B2`, the user have to enter the content of cell `B3`, `B5`,`B6`......`B10`...`B20` (but not cell `B4`). In order to make this, i think the possible way is to dim the cell colour of cell `B4` to let user know no need to enter the cell `B4`.

However, depends on the selection in cell `B2`, some cells in `B3` to `B20` may be dimmed case by case.

I have make a "criteria" sheet for reference which cells to be dimmed.

How to make it?
Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: sorry i don't know to write marco, so marco is not fit for me !!

Comment: have you looked at the help for conditional formatting, e.g. https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67

Comment: it doesn't help much

Comment: You know the office help teach us about the  one criteria or simple case.

Comment: For my case, there is a "criteria" sheet.

Comment: What does your criteria sheet look like?

Comment: my case is like that: when the user enter the "student name" in cell B2, then enter the marks on different subject. However, not all the student would take all the subjects. some would take subject XX, some take YY.

Comment: So, a criteria sheet marked all the subjects of each student take.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

[image]

Select B3:B10 and add a new CF rule, using the "use a formula" option, and enter:

```
 =NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&ROW()&"|",VLOOKUP(B$2,$E$2:$F$4,2,FALSE))))
```

The lookup table has the rows which should be "greyed out"